# Не работает модуль PyAutoGUI

Tags: python, pyautogui

Когда устанавливаю (`pip install puautogui`) то пишет что успешно установлена. А когда запускаю код выходит такая ошибка:

```
  File "D:\python\pyautogui2.py", line 1, in <module>   
    import pyautogui                                    
  File "D:\python\pyautogui.py", line 4, in <module>    
    print(pyautogui.position())                         
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pyautogui'
 has no attribute 'position' (most likely due to a circu
lar import)
```

Говорит что `pyautogui` не имеет атрибут `position`, но он имеет. И вообще говорит что ошибка в 1 строке тоже.

Вот код:

```
import pyautogui

print(pyautogui.position())

pyautogui.move(50, 50, duration=0.5)
pyautogui.moveTo(150, 200, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Говорит что pyautogui не имеет атрибут position, но он имеет.

Да, действительно такой атрибут имеется.

**Попробуйте сделать вот что:**

Первым делом, проверьте, не называется ли ваш python-файл **"pyautogui.py"**. Проверьте, нет ли рядом с вашим python-файлом другого файла **"pyautogui.py"**.

*Скорее всего, проблема именно в этом. Python воспринимает pyautogui как ваш файл, а не библиотеку*

**Если это исключено, то:**

1. Обновить *pip*: `pip install --upgrade pip`
2. После этого обновить *pyautogui*: `pip install --upgrade pyautogui`

**Если не поможет**, то попробуйте вручную установить библиотеку из [официального репозитория](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui)

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало!